# Does the .NET runtime internally map to win32 function calls?

Tags: .net, c, winapi, runtime

In other words, does the .NET framework eventually make calls somewhere to get its work done? Or did Microsoft completely re-create all the functionality of the win32 library in their .NET framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a mix. Obviously, things like winforms are largely wrappers around Win32 functionality (or a mix of both worlds), but WPF is a lot more managed (in terms of the actual control code; under the hood, as Mash notes, it may use DirectX for the rendering). Likewise, things like file/network access are (by necessity) wrappers around the OS objects, as are the unmanaged lock objects like `Mutex` - but many other things are 100% managed.

So it isn't a simple answer.

(edit) Also - keep in mind that ".NET" is a very vague term; Compact Framework, Micro Framework, Silverlight etc may have different, non-win32 implementations.

Comment: It's debatable whether WPF lot more managed, while internally it's heavily relies on DirectX...

Comment: So because .NET largely relies on win32 to get its work done, it could never "replace" it as the primary WINAPI, right?  Or is that the eventual goal?

Comment: the whole "managed OS" debate is a tricky one. I don't expect we'll see such a thing any time soon (if ever). It relies on some external services, which (for windows/.NET) is the Windows API. Others are possible, though - look at mono on linux, or Micro Framework on, heck, a wrist watch.

Answer (score 6):

A .NET application is just another Win32 process, so there is no magic and obviously it is going to use the underline operating system. Even the .NET libraries use Win32 to a great extent.

Examples:

- Memory management is handled
  internally for managed code, but for
  the process itself it is handled just
  like any other Win32 process.
- Currently managed threads are
  implemented as OS threads as well.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** realised I answered the wrong question (you said runtime not class library)...oh well I'll keep the guff below in anyway!

It depends on the part of the library:

- System.Xml library **doesn't** use MSXML
- System.Reflection won't as it's all IL based
- System.Text does and doesn't. There are some 'fast' calls for string manipulation
- System.Text.RegularExpressions doesn't, like the XML namespace it's all custom using a RegexRunner internal class.
- System.Diagnostics uses kernel32.dll calls such as CreateProcess
- System.IO namespace does pinvoke also
- System.Threading uses internal method calls which will eventually (inside the CLR) call winapi methods
- System.Windows.Forms is a mixture but eventually uses GDI
- System.Net (NetworkStream) uses ws2_32.dll such as WSARecv(..)

That's just from fiddling with Reflector. Obviously being a COM server the Microsoft CLR relies heavily on win32 too.

Answer (score 5):

In some cases (most, perhaps? I haven't reflected through the entire framework) the .NET framework makes calls to win32. Most controls are simply win32-controls wrapped with a few new features.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it calls win32 functions internally. For example the OpenRead method in File class contains:

```
    return new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

and it will eventually call:

```
    SafeFileHandle handle = CreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, securityAttrs, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);
```

which is a win32 native function, deep down in the method.

Answer (score 2):

[Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an implementation of the .net runtime, and it certainly doesn't map to win32 function calls (at least on linux)

I guess your question was referring to Microsoft implementation of the .net runtime.

Answer (score 1):

It does call the .NET API as all Windows applications do. But it is more than just a simple wrapper or map, it is more accurately described as an abstraction.