# Does RijndaelManaged .NET call Windows API

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, aes

Looking at the official documentation of `Filestream.Read`, it does call the lower level Windows API function `ReadFile`, but I can't figure out if this is also the case for e.g. `RijndaelManaged` or `AESManaged`,  are there indirect calls to the Windows `CryptoAPI`? In other words: when a malicious .NET binary calls `AESManaged`, does this result in calls to the Windows API?

e.g. does this result in an indirect Windows API call (for example `BCryptEncrypt`):

```
    public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        byte[] salt = new byte[]
        {
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8
        };
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelManaged = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                rijndaelManaged.KeySize = 256;
                rijndaelManaged.BlockSize = 128;
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 1000);
                rijndaelManaged.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.KeySize / 8);
                rijndaelManaged.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(rijndaelManaged.BlockSize / 8);
                rijndaelManaged.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, rijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                }
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792603/does-the-net-runtime-internally-map-to-win32-function-calls short answer is probably. You can take a look at cryptsp.dll on a disassembler for some of the winapi crypto functions. At the end of the day it depends on what it's actually being done. Like, opening a file on .NET will most likely end up being a call to NtOpenFile.  If you mean Native API as in ntdll, to my knowledge it doesn't provide crypto functions. So this is most likely being done in a usermode dll. I'm upvoting this as I'm also curious about it

Comment: The Managed postfix means it's implemented using only managed code.

Comment: @SimonMourier aah Okay, so that means the Windows CryptoAPI is not called in any stage, not directly and not indirectly..?

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the [RijndaelManaged](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rijndaelmanaged.cs) and [RijndaelManagedTransform](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rijndaelmanagedtransform.cs) classes

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your input, based on this documentation it doesn't look like it calls a Windows API function, none of the functions call the Windows CryptoAPI

Comment: the goal of my entire existence is to care about useless things